# Uniform bound for $cos(nz)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

One of my friend's professor gave him a question that $\cos(nz)$ is uniformly bounded in the open unit disk. I do not believe it is since setting $z=1/2i$, $\cos(nz) = \frac{e^{-n/2}+e^{n/2}}{2}$ which blows up as n increases. Anything I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: open disk around which point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\Bbb{C}=\bigcup_n nB$, where $B$ is the open unit disk, it is easy to see that the sequence of functions $(z\mapsto f(n z))_n$ on the unit disk is uniformly bounded if and only if $f$ is bounded. Since your $f$ is holomorphic, this is the case (by Liouville) if and only if it is constant, but the Cosine is not constant.

So, no, you are not missing anything.